# "Duplicate Resources" error when building Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

When I build my Android app, I get this error:

```
Error:Error: Duplicate resources: E:\Android\LED\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\login_bg.png:drawable-hdpi-v4/login_bg, E:\Android\LED\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\login_bg.9.png:drawable-hdpi-v4/login_bg
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> E:\Android\LED\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\login_bg.png: Error: Duplicate resources: E:\Android\LED\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\login_bg.png:drawable-hdpi-v4/login_bg, E:\Android\LED\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\login_bg.9.png:drawable-hdpi-v4/login_bg
```

I am not able to properly understand the error. What file is duplicated here? What am I supposed to do to rectify it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this error is because Android considers the following images to be the same, based on how they are referenced in your layouts:

```
E:\Android\LED\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\login_bg.png
E:\Android\LED\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\login_bg.9.png
```

The first image, `login_bg.png`, is a normal image. The second image, `login_bg.9.png`, is named in such a way to tell Android that it is a 9-patch image. However, in terms of referencing the images, they are declared the same, as in the following examples.

Normal image:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/normalImage"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg"/>
```

Nine-patch image:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ninePatchImage"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg"/>
```

Note: There is no difference in terms of referencing the images from the `/res/drawables` directory of your Android project.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) for more info about nine-patch image, or the correct term for it is nine-patch drawable. For reference, nine-patch drawables *must* be declared as `<name>.9.png`, as in `login_bg.9.png`.

Therefore, simply renaming them will not solve the issue. You need to check with whoever developed the UI to see which one should be used: either the normal image (`login_bg.png`) or the 9-patch image (`login_bg.9.png`)—not both.

Answer (score 15):

This error message will occur whenever the build tools detect multiple files with same name, regardless of their extension type.

For example, a file named `mypicture.jpg` cannot be in the same folder as `mypicture.png`.

In your case, `login_bg.9.png` and `login_bg.png` cannot be in the same directory.

Therefore, what you need to do is change the name of (or delete) one of the files.

Answer (score 8):

Delete the image from drawable directory, because you are using same name within one folder, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 6):

Solved this by going to

Build ➞ Clean Project

Answer (score 5):

After I changed the initial/default ic_launcher via
 `Resource Manager>>Image Asset>>Icon Type>> Launcher Icons`
I got this error.
It happens because the initial icon still exists and with the same name inside the `mipmap` folder.

the solution for me was to delete the initial launcher icon.

**Solution**:  Change your view to Project, find the initial icon, and delete it, then the error should be gone.

[image: how to find and delete the initial icon]

Answer (score 0):

Using Ant instead of Gradle seemed to fix the issue for me.  Many of my files have the same filename to start with a different extension (indexed resource files of various types).  Ancient project, and the ancient solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I find a same string name in my two diff `.xml` file,

```xml
//a.xml
<string name="dialog_subscribe">关注</string>
```

```xml
//b.xml
<string name="dialog_subscribe">subscribe</string>
```

then i solved it by rename one of then