# Phonegap generating both screen.png and screen.9.png for splash screens

Tags: android, cordova, nine-patch

I'm having a difficult time getting my splash screens to work right in Phonegap for Android. Note: I'm using Phonegap CLI and with Eclipse, I'm not using Phonegap Build.

I originally created a set of png images to use for the various image densities and alignments - port-hdpi, etc. We had a problem with the images being stretched under certain circumstances so I'm now trying to make use of 9 patch images - a trial in itself.

I've modified my various png's to be 9 patch images using the draw9patch tool and I've named them all with the .9.png extension. I modified my config.xml to use these images, with entries such as:

```
<splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.9.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
```

When I try to build the project, I get errors similar to the following:

```
[aapt] res/drawable-land-hdpi-v4/screen.png:0: error: Resource entry screen is already defined.
[aapt] res/drawable-land-hdpi-v4/screen.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
```

I check my drawable folder and sure enough there is both a screen.png and a screen.9.png. The screen.png appears to be a duplicate of my 9 patch image. When I remove the various screen.png files and build the project in Eclipse, it works (sort of - still having issues with stretchable areas).

Is this a bug with Phonegap or am I missing something that is causing it to generate both screen.png and screen.9.png?

Comment: I have this exact same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue as well. Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547287/android-error-duplicate-resources

Comment: I've logged the issue here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11448